# Move one local repo files/history in to another local repo

Tags: git

I'm in a situation where I need to move the files of one repo `/path/to/repoA` in to a sub directory of another repo `/path/to/repoB/repoA` and preserve its history if possible. The only answer's I've seen so was doing this between a local and remote repo and involved using a URL to identify the parent repo.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve (i.e. how the imported repo should behave), there are several different options to choose.  One of them is using `git subtree`, as described in [*Pro Git* book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html):

```
cd /path/to/repoB
git remote add repoA /path/to/repoA
git fetch repoA
git read-tree --prefix=repoA/ -u repoA/master
git commit -m "import repoA"
```